# Update the first value of a dictionary

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of multiple dictionaries.

The structure of my dictionaries are like that :

`{'word': 'hello world', 'definition': 'saying hello to the world'}`

I would like to update only the first value, so here 'hello world' in order to have it in upper case.
Here is my comprehension list i'm trying with:

`upper = {key: value.upper()[0] for key, value in words_dict.items()}`

The problem is that with this I have this result:
`{'word': 'H', 'definition': 'S'}`

I've tried loads of things but I'm still blocked...

Comment: `words_dict["word"] = words_dict["word"].upper()` Dictionaries don't really have a "first" value, they're insertion-ordered, sure, but the idea of order in a dictionary is somewhat meaningless as they are intended to be used as mappings. In order to modify a specific value, you need to access that specific value.

Comment: that easy of course... thanks a lot ! edit: thanks for the extra explanation

Comment: Do you want `"Hello World"` or do you want `"HELLO WORLD"`?

Comment: "HELLO WORLD" so your solution worked just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
upper = {key: words_dict[key].upper() if idx==0 else words_dict[key] for idx, key in enumerate(words_dict.keys())}
```

But using a dictionary comprehension here is hardly very readable. Perhaps a more readable approach would be to copy the dictionary and then just modify the first element.

```
upper = words_dict.copy()
first = list(upper.keys())[0]
upper[first] = upper[first].upper()
```

If you want to update the original dictionary, obviously operate on the original instead of on a copy.

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension is not very useful if all you want is to change the first item of the dict. You can change the dict in-place.

One way of doing it, without specifying the key name:

```
words_dict[next(iter(words_dict))] = words_dict[next(iter(words_dict))].upper()
```